# Деплой мавен проекта на томкэт

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

При деплое через консоль mvn tomcat7:deploy - все успешно, но когда я нажимаю в intellij idea на деплой выдает это. Полдня мучаюсь. Вижу что вызывает дефолтовый деплой. Получается мне нужно как то прописать вызов tomcat7:deploy  а не дефолтовый.

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.spring4soap</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring4soap</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Spring 4 Soap</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <!--    <distributionManagement>
            <repository>
                <id>TomcatServer</id>
                <url>http://tomcathost:8080/manager/text</url>
            </repository>
        </distributionManagement>-->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/</schemaDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>

                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://tomcathost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <path>/webapp</path>
                    <username>admin</username>
                    <password>admin</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Вывод**

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java" "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\Sergey.I.Shevtsov\Desktop\Spring4SoapProducer - копия" -Xmx512m -Dmaven.home=C:\apache-maven-3.3.9 -Dclassworlds.conf=C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\m2.conf -Didea.launcher.port=7550 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;C:\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2016.3.2 deploy
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Spring 4 Soap 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.6:xjc (xjc) @ spring4soap ---
[INFO] No changes detected in schema or binding files - skipping source generation.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ spring4soap ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ spring4soap ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ spring4soap ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Sergey.I.Shevtsov\Desktop\Spring4SoapProducer - копия\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ spring4soap ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ spring4soap ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.6:war (default-war) @ spring4soap ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [spring4soap] in [C:\Users\Sergey.I.Shevtsov\Desktop\Spring4SoapProducer - копия\target\spring4soap-1]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\Sergey.I.Shevtsov\Desktop\Spring4SoapProducer - копия\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [121 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\Sergey.I.Shevtsov\Desktop\Spring4SoapProducer - копия\target\spring4soap-1.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ spring4soap ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\Sergey.I.Shevtsov\Desktop\Spring4SoapProducer - копия\target\spring4soap-1.war to C:\Users\Sergey.I.Shevtsov\.m2\repository\com\spring4soap\spring4soap\1\spring4soap-1.war
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\Sergey.I.Shevtsov\Desktop\Spring4SoapProducer - копия\pom.xml to C:\Users\Sergey.I.Shevtsov\.m2\repository\com\spring4soap\spring4soap\1\spring4soap-1.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ spring4soap ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.535 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-13T18:09:19+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/222M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project spring4soap: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В IDEA вы указываете цель `deploy`, а в консоли `tomcat7:deploy`. Это разные цели.

Для запуска нужной вам цели можно использовать таб Maven Projects

```
Maven Projects -> <Ваше приложение> -> Plugins -> tomcat7 -> tomcat7:deploy
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: подскажите как в idea указать цель tomcat7:deploy чтобы происходил деплой

Comment: а как вы запускаете эту цель? через таб Maven Projects?

Comment: да. коллега попросил чтобы деплой происходил при нажатии на кнопку деплой в табе Maven Projects))

Comment: я добавил картинку в ответ

Comment: вот это я то я как раз и не смог найти(неправильно искал видимо). Спасибо большое!)